# Rewriting subfolders using nice url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

When I go to `http://www.example.com/youtube/detail/abvcde` in my browser, I want to internally rewrite the url to `http://www.example.com/youtube/detail.php?id=abvcde`. I tried to do this with the following .htaccess, but it gives a 404 error.

Currently my .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Please add more details.

Comment: When writing a question, make sure to always include a clear problem statement. "It does not work" is an understatement. You would not come here if your code worked absolutely fine. Instead focus on what you see: Do you get an error, does your computer catch fire, do purple unicorns wander over your screen. Based on your code I am assuming you get a 404 error, but please edit your question if this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following code in a htaccess file in server root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^youtube/detail/(.+)$ youtube/detail.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put this code in your `/youtube/.htaccess`

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /youtube/

RewriteRule ^detail/([^/]+)$ detail.php?id=$1 [L]
```